# How to delete last executed liquibase changeset from database

Tags: liquibase

I accidently ran this changeset, but I want to do some modification to this changeset. This is still in development mode, so I do not want to add another changeset to revert these changes.
I am planning to delete PAYLOAD_SIZE column from the table by executing sql query directly in database. After that I want to run the changeset again by doing some modification.

From the liquibase documentation I understand that liquibase creates an entry in table DATABASECHANGELOG for successfully executed changeset. So I am planning to delete the entry corresponding to changeset "ADD_PAYLOADSIZE" from table DATABASECHANGELOG.
Will it cause any inconsistency by deleting entry from DATABASECHANGELOG please suggest.

```
<changeSet author="*****" id="ADD_PAYLOADSIZE">
        <addColumn tableName="METER_DATA">
            <column name="PAYLOAD_SIZE" type="BIGINT" defaultValue="0"></column>
        </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it wont cause any inconsistency as long as you make these two changes (manually delete the payload size column and remove the entry for this changeset from the DATABASECHANGELOG table)